# Salesforce-Execute method of the queuable apex is not running

Tags: queueable

I have written the following queuable class :

```
public class LeadTriggerQueueable implements Queueable{ 
    list<Rejected_Hold_List__c> lstRejectedLead = new list<Rejected_Hold_List__c>();

    public LeadTriggerQueueable(list<Rejected_Hold_List__c> lstRejectedLead){

        this.lstRejectedLead = lstRejectedLead;
        system.debug('####lstRejectedLeadConstructor '+lstRejectedLead);
    }

    //Method to create insert records for an sobject
     public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
         system.debug('####Inside execute');
         insert lstRejectedLead;
         system.debug('####lstRejectedLeadExecute '+lstRejectedLead);
     }
}
```

But my execute method fails to run. I am calling this class from before insert trigger. I am not sure if i am missing something in here. Can someone point in right direction?

Comment: Have you checked your debug logs after trying to schedule this class in your trigger? (You haven't provided your trigger, so I can only assume that you are indeed scheduling the class.) Since it's an asynchronous operation, it'll show up as a separate log file (separate from the log file you get when your trigger that schedules this class executes).

Comment: Hi Derek, In my debuf i am able to get the system.debug('####lstRejectedLeadConstructor '+lstRejectedLead); in the constructor but the one in the execute is not there in the debug logs. I did not get the separate log and i checked jobs as well, queueable job was not there in the queue as well. So the execute method did not run at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to surmise that you are trying to log objects that are failing some validation logic in your `before insert` trigger. If they fail, such as with `.addError()`, then the transaction fails and no queueables will execute by definition (nor will any asynchronous execute except Platform Event publishing)

Comment: So i should take off my .addError() if i need to get my queueable executed? If I take off add,error() , then my lead will be inserted and also the log object will be inserted .Is there a workaround to prevent the leads from getting inserted and only add the log object.

Comment: @SFDCSana14 - the only way to log errors and still reject the transaction is to use Platform Events to publish the log data and then consume via a trigger.  Read the doc on Platform Events for details.